# Postgis/Postgres 9.3 query create table

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgis, create-table, sqlfiddle

I am trying to create a table in sql fiddle (Postgres 9.3) using the following command to create geometry coordinate.

```
create table geoCordinate(Coordinate geometry,Place varchar(30), name int);
```

And trying to insert following values:

```
INSERT INTO geoCordinate VALUES 
( ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=312;POINT(37.457797 -122.161298)'), '1', 1 ),
( ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=312;POINT(37.423629 -122.174416)'), '1', 2 ),
( ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=312;POINT(37.45774 -122.118724)'), '1', 3 ),
( ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=312;POINT(37.442434 -122.115522)'), '1', 4 ),
  ( ST_GeomFromEWKT('SRID=312;POINT(37.44862 -122.136768)'), '1', 5);
```

But I am getting the following error :

```
 ERROR:  type "geometry" does not exist
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL Fiddle does not support the PostGIS extension, i.e. normally installed with:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
```

however, this raises:

> ERROR: could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/postgis.control": No such file or directory

Beyond this, there are several issues with your geometries... (no typmods, invalid SRID, reversed axis order)